# Regex Remove Square Brackets/Whitespace

Tags: regex

I'm trying to cleanup some user input using a Regex to remove both [ and ] and also delete any whitespaces greater than 1 space. But I just can't seem to pull off the effect I am after. This is my first time using Regex so I am a bit stumped on how to write it out.

```
(preg_replace("[\[\]]\s{2,}"), "", $source);
```

That is what I am using to basically format

```
[Hello World    ]
```

In to

```
Hello World
```

However when I enter the info, it seems to delete the entire thing.

Comment: Don't you mean `Hello World` (with the capital `W`) as the result?

Comment: Yes, capital W it was a typo. Will fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alternation:

```
$result = preg_replace("/[[\]]|\s{2,}/", "", $source);
```

You're also missing the [PCRE delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (the `/` at the beginning and end).

Note that in the case of `Hello  World` (with two spaces) will become `HelloWorld`.  You can also do multiple replacements:

```
$result = preg_replace(array("/[[\]]/", "\s+"), array("", " "), $source);
```

Comment: This still seems to delete the entire string, not the [ ] or whitespaces. Tried both lines.

Comment: Nevermind I got it working, I was using real_escape_string in the wrong place as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try these regex

```
preg_replace('/\[.*\]/', '', $str);
preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate regex replacements:

```
/[\[\]]/ → ""

/\s(\W)/ → "$1"
```

---

This way, something like `Hello  World` (with two spaces) would be turned into `Hello World` instead of `HelloWorld`, but `Hello World !` would still become `Hello World!`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "[Hello World     ]    ";
print preg_replace("/\[|\]|\s{2,}/", "", $test);
```

Answer (score 0):

this might not be what you were thinking of, but you could select just the words, and then trim it.

```
r'\w+\s' == 'Hello World '
trim()   == 'Hello World'
```

Comment: `\w+\s` extracts words with following spaces. It does not remove brackets or extra space, and any other punctuation will also be removed.